# Lenovo Carbon X1 6th gen Trackpad stopped working on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

The trackpad and trackpoint just stopped working. I guess as a result of a system update (I might not have noticed exactly when because I use another mouse)

All the previous trick doesn't work (playing with the blacklisted module `blacklist i2c_i801` - which was previously commented out in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`)

I've tried to disable the Secure Boot, to disable the trackpoint in the BIOS. 
No effect the pointer is not moving with the trackpad.

```
➜ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse                   id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3288-011                      id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
➜ uname -a
Linux bertrand-x1pad 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

Or I have the feeling it is disabled somewhere. I'm stuck. any advise ?

Comment: asking the "obvious" question, but you tried the `fn` key + `F11` (ain't got same machine but think that is the enable/disable track pad for X1)? If `fn-lock` enabled, press `F11` w.o. holding `fn` key.

Comment: Yes I've checked all possible settings, etc. I'm not sure how to get more info, dmesg maybe but I don't know what to search

Comment: Seems to be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1855240. No response as of 05/Dec...

Comment: Thanks I've switch to another kernel version and it looks like it fixes the problem. I'll dig a bit to see if it's actually related to this bug.

Comment: Kernel version 4.15.0.74 solves the issue for me. Give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE (Jan 7th 2020): The issue is now fixed for me on kernel version 4.15.0.74. I was able to reinstall linux-generic and get back to regular kernel updates.

Upon further investigation, the issue is clearly related to kernel version 4.15.0.72. For now, booting to the previous version (4.15.0.70) makes the touchpad work for me. I guess I will wait to upgrade until the bug is fixed...

To boot into this version, select it from your Grub menu on startup. I went one step further and uninstalled version .72, although made a note to reinstall the package 'linux-generic' again once the bug is fixed (that is a metapackage that always depends on the latest kernel, its what keeps your kernel up-to-date).

Not so much a solution as just a workaround for now...

Link to bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798

Answer (score 0):

I had an X1 Carbon (7th gen) where the trackpad wouldn't work at all (although I'm pretty sure it used to do so, and only fail occasionally after a suspend cycle.  I did two things, 1) add a file `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf` containing the line

```
 option psmouse synaptics_intertouch=1
```

and 2) installing the synaptics driver by running `apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.  (The latter is probably installed by default with desktop Ubuntu, but I install a minimal system and add the things I want, so I run into weird configuration problems like this).

Not tested extensively, but after a few suspend cycles and various USB connects and disconnects, the trackpad keeps working.  This is on Ubuntu 19.10, so kernel is 5.3.0-26-generic.